# Manipulating data in C# Set operations

Tags: c#, set

I have two lists of dictionary on which I am doing set operations. I will illustrate what I am doing and what I am trying to achieve as an example:

```
var A = new List<Dictionary<string, int>>();
var B = new List<Dictionary<string, int>>();

A.Add(new Dictionary <string, int> { {"KeyA",1}, {"KeyB", 2} });
A.Add(new Dictionary <string, int> { {"KeyA",3}, {"KeyB", 5} });
B.Add(new Dictionary <string, int> { {"KeyA",6}, {"KeyB", 8}, {"KeyC", 11} });
B.Add(new Dictionary <string, int> { {"KeyA",3}, {"KeyB", 7}, {"KeyC", 15} });

var result = A.Intersect(B, new KeyComparer("KeyA"));
```

This gives me back the list of A using KeyA for intersection and I get a single row with `{"KeyA",3}, {"KeyB", 5}` as the result. What if I want to add `{KeyC, 15}` from B to the result when intersection has happened.

I hope I am clear with the question.

Answer (score 0):

If I've correctly understood your question, you want to add some other item to the sequence once you've done the intersection... and then, what you need is `Enumerable.Concat`:

```
var result = A.Intersect(B, new KeyComparer("KeyA"))
               .Concat(B.Last().Where(pair => pair.Key == "KeyC"));
```